# OpenLayers 6 and Font Awesome 5 showing boxes instead of icon

Tags: javascript, font-awesome-5, openlayers-6

I've tried various already suggested solutions but none worked.

I have a simple style

```
new Style({
    text: new Text({
        text: '\uf0d1',
        scale: 1.5,
        textBaseline: 'bottom',
        font: '900 20px Font Awesome 5 Free',
        fill: new Fill({ color: '#2196F3' }),
    }),
})
```

And this is what is showed on the map

[image]

Only the box is showed instead of the icon.

To add, this is the Vue project with Nuxt, so the Font Awesome is imported via `next-fontawesome` package and used across the project via component tags.

In my main scss file I have added `@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css';` and tested on basic span like this

```
<span class="custom-icon"></span>
```

and in css

```
.custom-icon::before {
       font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
       font-weight: 900;
       content: "\f007";
       color: green;
 }
```

which resulted in this
[image]

So the codes are working fine but not on the map.

If anybody knows what is the problem I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out if anybody needs it for future reference

1. Make sure that `@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css` is imported in global CSS
2. Font name should be quoted like `font: '900 20px "Font Awesome 5 Free"'`